# Why do the aircraft made by the Soviet Union have fans in their cockpits?

Tags: aircraft-design, cockpit

Surely the countries which were a part of the Soviet Union were not so hot then why are there fans in their cockpits? e.g. TU-134

[image]

or IL-76

[image]

or AN-124

[image]

Comment: It keeps the Russian pilots from sticking their heads out the window to feel the breeze.

Comment: Because air conditioning was too expensive.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri, I don't think you can have a pressurization system without ability to control temperature, or that it would be any cheaper, so for pressurized aircraft—and all the pictured ones are—the air conditioning is ‘free’, because it is already included in the pressurization system.